# Groovy map - group and sum by two keys

Tags: groovy, maps

I have this data

```
Country:"USA", Gender:"Male", Count:100
Country:"USA", Gender:"Male", Count:300
Country:"USA", Gender:"Female", Count:200
Country:"USA", Gender:"Non-binary", Count:50
Country:"France", Gender:"Male", Count:10
Country:"France", Gender:"Female", Count:30
Country:"France", Gender:"Female", Count:10
```

As you can see, I have several lines with the same combination of Country & Gender.

I need to create a new map - group Country & Gender and sum the Count for this group.

I can arrange the map as I wish –

```
[Country:"USA", Gender:"Male", Count:100] 
or 
[[Country:"USA", Gender:"Male"]:100]]
```

My Questions:

1. How to best create the map for grouping
2. How to sum the groups

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `groupBy` with some additions:

```
List data = [
[Country:"USA", Gender:"Male", Count:100],
[Country:"USA", Gender:"Male", Count:300],
[Country:"USA", Gender:"Female", Count:200],
[Country:"USA", Gender:"Non-binary", Count:50],
[Country:"France", Gender:"Male", Count:10],
[Country:"France", Gender:"Female", Count:30],
[Country:"France", Gender:"Female", Count:10],
]

Map groupped = data.groupBy{ [ Country:it.Country, Gender:it.Gender ] }

groupped.each{ group, vals -> group.sum = vals*.Count.sum() }

println groupped.entrySet().join( '\n' )
```

prints

```
{Country=USA, Gender=Male, sum=400}=[{Country=USA, Gender=Male, Count=100}, {Country=USA, Gender=Male, Count=300}]
{Country=USA, Gender=Female, sum=200}=[{Country=USA, Gender=Female, Count=200}]
{Country=USA, Gender=Non-binary, sum=50}=[{Country=USA, Gender=Non-binary, Count=50}]
{Country=France, Gender=Male, sum=10}=[{Country=France, Gender=Male, Count=10}]
{Country=France, Gender=Female, sum=40}=[{Country=France, Gender=Female, Count=30}, {Country=France, Gender=Female, Count=10}]
```

You can grab map's keys:

```
println groupped.keySet().join( '\n' )
```

you'll get:

```
[Country:USA, Gender:Male, sum:400]
[Country:USA, Gender:Female, sum:200]
[Country:USA, Gender:Non-binary, sum:50]
[Country:France, Gender:Male, sum:10]
[Country:France, Gender:Female, sum:40]
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. 
How do I get only the first part? ie [Country=USA, Gender=Male, sum=400]